# Login form disappear when logged in

Tags: php, html

Pretty much I have a page called index.php and a login button at the top with 2 forms:
Username and password.

I want to be able to login and then I get redirected to the SAME page but with the login forms gone..#

obviously:

```
<?php
if($_SESSION['username'])
     echo "welcome, ".$_SESSION['username']."!<br><a href='logout.php'> logout</a> ";
else 
     "CODE FOR FORM GOES HERE"
?>
```

would not work..

Comment: In what way will your pseudo code obviously not work? As asked this question is too vague to be on topic.

Comment: I would suggest redirecting to a different file if the user is already logged in. But we're gonna need to see more code if you really want to do it this way.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding curly brackets.

```
<?php
if($_SESSION['username']){
     echo "welcome, ".$_SESSION['username']."!<br><a href='logout.php'> logout</a> ";
}else{ 
     //CODE FOR FORM GOES HERE
}
?>
```